# FileInputStream vs FileReader / FileOutputStream vs FileWriter

Tags: java, android-sdk, android

Набрел на такой пример работы с файлами.

Для считывания файла в приложении:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      openFileInput(FILENAME)));
```

Для считывания файла на SD:

```
File sdFile = new File(sdPath, FILENAME_SD);
try {
  // открываем поток для записи
  BufferedReader br = new BuffereReader(new FileReader(sdFile));
```

Почему бы там и там не использовать поток или файл?
Я понимаю зачем использовать поток, в него передается имя файла и потом можно считывать по байтам, далее уже декораторы, по символьно и построчно.
Но зачем создавать объект File, также передавать ему имя файла, также считывать его и результат, вроде как, один?

**В чем разница?**

Слышал, что поток воспринимается как бесконечная часть кода из которой можно считывать.
А файл, вроде как, имеет определенную длину.
Может в этом дело?

Тогда из этого следует следующий вопрос:
**В чем преимущества одного перед другим?**

Comment: Stream (аутпут или инпут) - это работник с байтами вообщето, а Writer/Reader приспособлен для работы с символами. Также InputStreamReader (который является переходником) можно передать кодировку. И помечай вопросы нормальными, релевантными метками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница исключительно в том, что `openFileInput` открывает вам файл относительно того каталога, куда установлено ваше приложение - второй же способ открывает произвольный файл по абсолютному пути.

В конечном итоге получается одно и то же - используйте тот способ, который вам удобнее.